# NLog is not deleting old files

Tags: nlog

I have the below config for NLog (4.7.11), which creates a new log file every day or when the file is overgrown. The problem: it is not deleting the old files at all so now the log folder is full of many weeks old log files. Can you please suggest what's wrong and how to get it work?

```
<target name="appLogFile" type="File"
 fileName="d:\my_logs\nlog_test-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
 archiveFileName="d:\my_logs\nlog_test-{#}.log" 
 archiveAboveSize="104857600" archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
 maxArchiveFiles="2" maxArchiveDays="2"
 openFileCacheTimeout="30" concurrentWrites="True" keepFileOpen="True" createDirs="True"
 layout="${date:format=yyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff K} ${message}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like, you are logging into different files each day because the file names are created with the current date. On the next day, logging is done to the new file. When the replacing is not happening to the current file then the archive is not created until the maximum size is reached.

Please try the bellow configuration,

```
<target name="appLogFile" type="File"
 fileName="d:\my_logs\nlog_test.log"
 archiveFileName="d:\my_logs\archives\nlog_test-{#}.log" 
 archiveAboveSize="104857600" archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
 maxArchiveFiles="2" maxArchiveDays="2"
 openFileCacheTimeout="30" concurrentWrites="True" keepFileOpen="True" createDirs="True"
 layout="${date:format=yyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff K} ${message}" />
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense why archive process is not kicking in, and it seems it would only delete files with *<date>.<seq>.log suffix anyway.
Note your config results in different time (and sequence) stamp on the log files. I originally wanted to avoid too much renames as our files are consumed by Splunk Monitor, but luckily it seems it handles file rollovers smoothly. So based on this I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: yes, you are right. Also ,In my configuration archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"  
 and archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"  are not required too. That I added by mistake while copied. And layout can be altered a bit.

Answer (score 1):

NLog 4.5 (and newer) makes it easy to do file-archive with dynamic-layout:

```xml
<target name="appLogFile" type="File"
 fileName="d:\my_logs\nlog_test-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
 archiveAboveSize="104857600"
 maxArchiveFiles="2" maxArchiveDays="2"
 openFileCacheTimeout="30" concurrentWrites="True" keepFileOpen="True"
 layout="${date:format=yyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff K} ${message}" />
```

By removing `archiveFileName` + `archiveNumbering` + `archiveDateFormat`.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic